# PyPy 3.5 (Windows) does not contain bin directory

Tags: python, pypy, bin

I have just installed PyPy 3.5 (32-bit version) under Windows 10 and everything seems to be there, apart from the bin directory. That means that I don't have pip at my disposal and thus can't install additional packages.

Is there a way to get it installed properly?

This question refers to PyPy and not to CPython!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows).  Unless if this doesn't work, please reply though either way.

Comment: Did you try the instructions from PyPy's [Downloading and Installing PyPy](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html#installing-more-modules) page?

Answer (score 1):

PyPy, like CPython, includes pip and setuptools. You should open a CMD command line windows, cd to the directory with the pypy.exe or pypy3.exe file, and execute `pypy -mensurepip` or `pypy3 -ensurepip`

Comment: But the problem is that there is no directory where these programs reside (should be the bin directory). In 2.7 it’s all there, but not in 3.5.